# Unable to resolve org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Specified firefox binary location does not exist or is not a real file?

Tags: firefox, amazon-web-services

We are getting "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Specified firefox binary location does not exist or is not a real file: /usr/local/bin/firefox/firefox" exception when we ran the selenium web driver code via linux

Configuration:
aws-cli/1.7.38 Python/2.7.9 Linux/3.14.48-33.39.amzn1.x86_64
Amazon ElasticBeanStalk

Already installed firefox on /usr/local/bin/firefox/firefox

when i ran firefox --version the version clearly getting displayed in the console

Mozilla Firefox 38.1.0

```
File pathToBinary = new File("/usr/local/bin/firefox/firefox");
FirefoxBinary ffBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathToBinary);
fBinary.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY", ":1");
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffBinary,pro);
```

xvfb is already started. (Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1280x768x24)

Please kindly help me on how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurred due to selenium library and firefox version conflict issue.